# mini_portile installation freezes on Digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, digital-ocean

I am trying to run bundle install.
All gems installs just fine but on **mini_portile** it freezes and after 10 mins it shows message

```
Killed. !
```

I tried to restart my droplet, then deleted this droplet created new again and so on.

But no solutions.

```
Error: Failed to build gem native extension
```

In error log I can see this message :

```
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2.. ERROR
```

My gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

#gem 'paperclip-watermark'
gem 'geo_ip'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'validates_email_format_of'
#gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails-addon'
#gem 'nifty-generators'
#gem 'ancestry'
gem 'judge', '~> 2.0.5'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.9'
gem 'inherited_resources', '~> 1.5.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
#gem "globalize3"
gem 'impressionist'
#gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'mailcatcher'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'rqrcode_png'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0' # Note: You MUST use 5.0.0 or greater for Rails 4.0+
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'devise'
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
```

Any help ?

thanks

Comment: I am suspecting this has got more to do with `nokogiri` and less with `mini_portile`. the error message with `libxml2` usually comes with `nokogiri`. Try installing both gems separately with `gem install mini_portile` and `gem install nokogiri`; that will show more details about why `bundle install` is failing.

Comment: You might not have enough RAM on the machine to compile Nokogiri.

Comment: @RyanBigg I found solution. I installed using this command 'NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install' 'and later on I upgraded my server from 512 RAM to 1 GB. Now It works just great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as suggested [here](https://github.com/flavorjones/mini_portile/issues/31) by @luislavena use:

`gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`

Comment: when using `gem "nokogiri"` in a Gemfile, is there any way to still specify the --use-system- ?